# OS X Yosemite is SUS - Single Unix Specification 3 certified. But what posix standard is it compliant to? the latest one is 2008

Tags: osx, posix, standard

I'm confused.  Is SUS compliance the same as POSIX compliance?  Is yosemite compliant to the latest standards, what years exactly?